# How much does it cost to add a new permission to an account?

Tags: ram, permissions, cpu, keys, net

When adding a new key pair to an existing account, how much RAM, CPU, and NET is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing with v1.5.1, adding a new permission to an account (set account):

Corresponding contract action: `updateauth`

RAM: 32 bytes
NET: 185 bytes
CPU: 320 time

for set action permission:

Corresponding contract action: `linkauth`

RAM: 144 bytes
NET: 127 bytes
CPU: 664 time

Important to know:

Ram usage is about using the storage, that means if update a permission (modifying a table index) it won't use additional ram.

From my experience, CPU usage fluctuates slightly.